# Select average of same days of past years

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a database with sales records of the type:

```
   DAY         PRODUCT1         PRODUCT2         PRODUCT3         TOTAL
date1(date) salesnumber(int) salesnumber(int) salesnumber(int)   sum(int)
date2(date) salesnumber(int) salesnumber(int) salesnumber(int)   sum(int)
   ...           ...              ...              ...             ...
```

It goes back to 7 years.
Now I need to get a sales average of each of my 3 products of the past 10 days records but for the past 5 years (e.g. average of 04/03/2014, 04/03/2013, 04/03/2012, 04/03/2011, 04/03/2010), so I can compare it with this years records to find the variation. Is there an easy way to do this? The output would be something like:

```
DATES           AVG(product1)      AVG(product2)     AVG(product3)     AVG(Total)             
todaydate       avg_last5years     avg_last5years    avg_last5years    avg_last5years
todaydate-1day  avg_last5years     avg_last5years    avg_last5years    avg_last5years
todaydate-2day  avg_last5years     avg_last5years    avg_last5years    avg_last5years
...              ...               ...               ...               ...
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? And could you explain your query a bit more, it's not that clear what you want? Also, some sample input/output data would help a lot.

Comment: Edited my question, hope its clearer, i'm using 2014 version.

Comment: You can use DATEPART()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want is the average of the sales made on the same date for the last five years for each product. If so I think this might be what you want:

```
select 
    s.day, 
    oa.*
from 
    sales s
outer apply (
    select 
       avg(product1*1.0) p1, 
       avg(product2*1.0) p2, 
       avg(product3*1.0) p3, 
       avg(total*1.0) total 
    from 
       sales
    where 
        day(day) = day(s.day) 
    and month(day) = month(s.day) 
    and year(day) >= year(s.day) - 5 
) oa
where 
    s.day between dateadd(day, -10, getdate()) and getdate()
```